# Making BackgroundImage of PictureBox Nothing

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make my BackgroundImage of a PictureBox nothing.

I've already tried

```
BackgroundImage3.BackgroundImage = Nothing
BackgroundImage3.Update() ' it didn't even work without this line of code
```

and

```
Dim n0 = Image
BackgroundImage3.BackgroundImage = n0
```

with no success.

Also, this is the code for the if statement, if it'll help a little:

```
If (PictureBox3.BackgroundImage Is My.Resources.theimageIwant) Then
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pictureboxes don't have a background image by default. How do you assign the background image in the first place? Just undo that.

Comment: I set it as one with the designer for default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was passing the same function (nothing then image) to another PictureBox right below it. Conflicts cause big problems. Thanks for helping everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In my Visual Studio 2010, this line works well:

```
BackgroundImage3.BackgroundImage = Nothing
```

After execution of this code, background image dissappears; that's what you trying to do?
I'm sure that the problem lies in the context where you've put your `BackgroundImage` change, so you can post your full code. Post complete procedure, in which you have placed the code above.